# Typescript types for Ramda chain when using own Monad

Tags: typescript, functional-programming, ramda.js

I'm trying to understand more about functional programing in typescript. So as an exercise I have written a `Reader` monad. But I'm having trouble with the types when working with ramda. Not sure how to understand the error message I'm getting. Hope someone can point me in the right direction.

Below is one of my tests. I have two functions that depend on values from the Reader and I want to pipe them. So I have to use chain for the second function. If I use my own `Reader.chain(stars)` I don't get any errors but when I try ramda `R.chain(stars)` I get an error from typescript, but the program works.

```
const hello = (name: string) =>
    Reader.asks(({ greeting }: { greeting: string }) => `${ greeting } ${ name }`)
const stars = (s: string) =>
    Reader.asks(({ stars }: { stars: boolean }) => `${ stars && '**' }${ s }`)
const program = R.pipe(
    hello,
    R.chain(stars),
)
const result = program('Alice').run({ greeting: 'Hello', stars: true })
expect(result).toEqual('**Hello Alice')
```

Error message for `R.chain(stars),` line:

```
No overload matches this call.
  The last overload gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'unknown[]' is not assignable to parameter of type '(x: Reader<{ greeting: string; }, string>) => unknown'.
      Type 'unknown[]' provides no match for the signature '(x: Reader<{ greeting: string; }, string>): unknown'.
```

code for my Reader implementation, most relevant will be the chain method, I removed methods that are not relevant:

```
class Reader<Context, Result> {
    constructor(private _exec: (context: Context) => Result){
    }

    public static asks<E, T>(fn: (context: E) => T): Reader<E, T>{
        return new Reader(fn)
    }

    public run(context: Context): Result{
        return this._exec(context)
    }

    public chain<A, B>(fn: (a: Result) => Reader<B, A>): Reader<Context & B, A>{
        return new Reader(context => fn(this._exec(context)).run(context))
    }

    public static chain = <Context, Result, A, B>(fn: (a: Result) => Reader<B, A>) =>
        (reader: Reader<Context, Result>): Reader<Context & B, A> =>
            reader.chain(fn)
}
```

I don't understand the error message and hope someone has an idea how to fix it or where i can read more about it.

Comment: Try changing `R.chain` to `Reader.chain`.

Comment: `Reader.chain` will work. But my question is more shouldn't it work with ramda too? Ramda clearly supports the functionality, the code runs, but i can't get rid of the type error.

Comment: I don’t know much about Ramda, but the [docs for `chain`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#chain) say that is meant for lists, not other monads.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time, but the second line says "Dispatches to the chain method of the second argument, if present, according to the FantasyLand Chain spec." Reader implements chain, what is part of why it is a monad. And the code runs, I get the right result. But somehow I messed up the types, or is this an error in the ramda types?

Comment: You might want to ask whoever maintains your Typescript typings file.  The Ramda team has little expertise in TS, so these have been external, although there has been discussion about bringing them in-house.  I know it's changing these days, but last I really paid attention, TS couldn't yet support all the signatures necessary to work seamlessly with Ramda.

Comment: Yep, [the types for `chain`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/da0e8712898499173a3149b175e6aa53b04a8b94/types/ramda/index.d.ts#L248-L2544) only seem to support lists or right-to-left composition.